# When import Theano, I got exception: "dot.exe" not found in path

Tags: python, theano

I am running python on Anaconda. I downloaded the Theano from "https://github.com/Theano/Theano.git" and installed it by running

```
cd Theano
python setup.py develop
```

However, when I tried to import the theano on Ipython notebook. I got the ""dot.exe" not found in path." exception. Have no clue what is going on...

```
import numpy as np
import time
import theano

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-432f5c01387b> in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import time
----> 3 import theano

c:\users\t-ninma\documents\studymaterials\theano\theano\__init__.py in <module>()
     79 from theano.misc.safe_asarray import _asarray
     80 
---> 81 from theano.printing import pprint, pp
     82 
     83 from theano.scan_module import scan, map, reduce, foldl, foldr, clone

c:\users\t-ninma\documents\studymaterials\theano\theano\printing.py in <module>()
     42                 pydot_imported_msg = "pydot can't find graphviz"
     43         else:
---> 44             pd.Dot.create(pd.Dot())
     45             pydot_imported = True
     46     except ImportError:

C:\Users\t-ninma\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pydot.pyc in create(self, prog, format)
   1874                 raise Exception(
   1875                     '"{prog}" not found in path.'.format(
-> 1876                         prog=prog))
   1877             else:
   1878                 raise

Exception: "dot.exe" not found in path.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are running anaconda in windows. When installing `Theano` in a windows machines sometimes there are some issues.

[Here](http://rosinality.ncity.net/doku.php?id=python:installing_theano) you can see a good way to install theano in windows machines. If you have installed any **mingw** compiler or **msys** before, remove then before following this method.

Hope this method will work..!